# Calculating Expected Return on Scratch-off tickets

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I came across this [article](https://www.indystar.com/story/news/investigations/2020/11/11/group-recent-princeton-grads-winning-lotteries-across-u-s/6146979002/) about a group of Princeton Grads who won the lottery a bunch of times. In the article it said most the winnings came from a gamed called `$7,000,000 MEGA CA$H`, which costs $30 per ticket. I took a look at the [rules](https://hoosierlottery.com/getmedia/33f6f7bf-f0e6-4265-bcbe-d4153b498b3b/2090-7million-mega-cash-rules.pdf?ext=.pdf) for the game and it seems that the tickets overall have a negative expected return. In the article it says most of the group's winnings came in the form of thousand dollar prizes, but if I reference the rules it says that the overall odds are 1 in 1503.24 for the thousand prize, so they should be losing money on average according to those rules. If that was the case then they probably wouldn't be doing this activity, so it seems I'm missing something and that's what I've been trying to figure out.

So, here are the odds for the tickets:
`($30/6.67)+($50/8.89)+($60/80.01)+($100/26.67)+($150/686.04)+($200/80.04)+($250/399.85)+($500/339.70)+($1000/1,503.24)+($10,000/32,301.68)+($25,000/80,754.20)+($250,000/1,345,903.33)+($7,000,000/2,691,806.67) = $23.5`
Based off of those calculations the average expected return on each ticket should be `-$6.5` since each ticket costs $30.

I was thinking if it was somehow possible to see if the expected return becomes positive depending on the number of unclaimed prizes. The unclaimed prizes for this particular lottery can be found by clicking on the "Prizes and Odds" button on the lottery website. Is there some way to calculate what the expected return on the remaining tickets are for this lottery? Not sure if I'm using the law of large numbers right but with this lottery there are 34,408 unclaimed tickets and 1,211,313 total winning tickets with $30 prizes.
`(34,408/1,211,313)*100 = 2.84%` So, according to my estimate 2.84% of tickets remain with 97.16% being sold.

Comment: MIT students found a way to make money off a Massachusetts lottery a few years back. Jordan Ellenberg wrote about it – see https://www.maa.org/meetings/calendar-events/how-to-get-rich-playing-the-lottery (but it sounds like the Princeton situation is different).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of how the MIT students did it, but this situation is indeed different. I already saw John Ellenberg's presentation and it was pretty great. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtlmXoHpNyI